# How to add jReject - jQuery Browser Rejection into Joomla1.5 web site

Tags: php, jquery, templates, frameworks, joomla

I want to add jReject - jQuery Browser Rejection into my Joomla website.  I just try out with adding JS files to my template folder and it doesnt work for me.

[jReject - jQuery Browser Rejection](http://jreject.turnwheel.com/)

How can I add browser compatibility warning to my web site. Any suggestions

I have added `jquery.reject.js` and `jquery.reject.css` into my template(gantry)

I have put `<head></head>` tags in my index.php and inside the those tags, added the following:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.reject.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="templates/gantry/js/jquery.reject.min.js"></script>   
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function{
            $.reject({
                reject: {
                    safari: true, // Apple Safari
                    chrome: true, // Google Chrome
                    firefox: true, // Mozilla Firefox
                    msie: true, // Microsoft Internet Explorer
                    opera: true, // Opera
                    konqueror: true, // Konqueror (Linux)
                    unknown: true // Everything else
                }
            }); // Customized Browsers    
            return false;
        });

</script>
```

Comment: Add the `jreject.js` file to your template folder, then include it in your template's `index.php`, and add the demo code from the site to the `$(document).ready(function{ //here });` instead of a button click like the demo's are. Tell us what errors you're getting and how far it gets not just `it doesn't work`.

Comment: i have added jquery.reject.js and jquery.reject.css into my template(gantry) .

Comment: and i have incleude things which i have enter to index.php bootom of my question .. please look into that.. still its not working @MrCode

Comment: I didnt get any errors, affter puting codes i try it on my safari 4.0.5 browser but no browser rejection messages displayed.. please advice

Comment: Have you verified that the `.js` file and css is included. View the source of the page in the browser and click the js and css links to make sure they are present.

Comment: those are ok. i have placed those includes top of the $(document).ready...etc script.

Comment: Are you including the jquery library as well? Verify jquery works first, put an alert or something inside the document ready and take out the reject stuff.

Comment: jquery library ? do i have to add that one also to js folder
i put alert like this , $(document).ready(function(){
$("a").click(function(event){
alert("Thanks for visiting!");
});
});
it also doesnt work

Comment: you need to include jquery like `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remember that Joomla is shipped with Mootools.
As you might know, both Mootools and jQuery share dollar sign `$` as shorthand for their functions, so remember to call `jQuery.noConflict()` or you're going to have some errors.

Since you want to display the popup only on some pages, you should create a module (maybe in an hidden position) and assign it to homepage only.
Please be aware that some text editor will strip away your javascript, so the best thing to do is to write plain text without any editors.

Hope this helps.